# Newly created databases are not replicating in mongo database

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

I am relatively new to Mongo database. Let me explain the issue. I might be missing something very obvious.

I have a 3 member replica set. One of the existing database is replicating properly (created a collection and verified), but when I create a new database using "use " it is not replicated to the other servers.

Comment: Okay, as expected. Silly mistake.

Just creating a database won't replicate that empty database across the replica sets. At least, an empty collection is mandatory to see the database being replicated.

Comment: did u add any records in the newly created database in the new collection ?

Comment: was my previous comment helpful ? ..just creating database wont replicate anything